# Ggplot2 stacked graph with 1200 values

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Hi ggplot2 warriors!

I am struggling with a stacked graph that contains about 1200 stacking values. 
I have a df with 4 variables

```
'data.frame':   4935 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ ISO3   : Factor w/ 133 levels "AGO","ALB","ARE",..: 23 105...
 $ band   : int  1 1 1 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 ...
 $ upbound: num  1000 1000 1000 2000 1000 1000 1000 2000 1000 1000 ...
 $ ET1    : num  3981 1280 1223 1096 772 ...
```

I need to plot country (ISO3) vs ET1, stacked by band.

Code:

```
library(dplyr); library(ggplot2); library(scales); library(ggsci); library(gridExtra); library(RColorBrewer); library(tidyr); library(reshape2)

#df
ex1 <- read.csv("example.csv")
ET <- select(ex, ET1) # used later 
ex <-  ex1  %>%  # to get descent values and graph according 
  arrange(desc(ET1, na.rm = TRUE))

#ex graph 
ggplot(data = ex) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = ISO3, fill = as.factor(upbound))) + #use as.factor to stack (correct?)
  theme(legend.position="none", text=element_text(size=25)) + # none because there are 1200 values in legend
  xlab("Country") + ylab("ET1") +
  coord_flip() + #tested up to here # save 1500x4000
  #scale_fill_continuous(aes(as.numeric(upbound)),breaks = c(500, 1000)) + #doesn't work
  #scale_x_log10(minor_breaks = log10(ET)) +#doesn't work
```

Here ex graph[image: ex]

```
#ex_a graph
ggplot(data = ex) + 
  geom_bar(mapping = aes(x = ISO3, fill = as.factor(upbound))) +
  theme(legend.position="bottom", text=element_text(size=25)) +
  xlab("Country") + ylab("ET1") +
  coord_flip() # save 1500x10000

#one solution could be 
#scale_fill_continuous(aes(as.numeric(band)),breaks = c(500, 1000)) # band instead of upbound # doesn’t work neither
```

Here ex_a graph [image: ex_a]

Issues: 1. Values do not descend as expected. 2. Colour for 1200 stacked values do not visualize nice. 3. Stacked should be done by band instead of upbound. 4. To have a better visualisation, I think to have a log scale for ET1 but doesn’t work neither. 5. After the flip, the graph should be country vs ET1, instead of country vs upbound.

Here a reproducible example: [example](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wMByYuHu970Slp6j6qdQII4eUVW3NKnx?usp=sharing)

I would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: "1. Values do not descend as expected". How do you expect them to descend? A. Which variable or metric do you want to sort through? B. Along which axis do you expect them to be sorted?

Comment: I expected them to descend by ET1 values. I need the final plot, in the x-axis = ET1, and in the y-axis = country (ISO3), and ET1 stacked by band.

Comment: But there are multiple ET1 values within observations of the same ISO3.   So, for instance, ISO3 == "CHN" has 1203 observations, with minimum value 0, max value 3981.141. What is the value you are expecting to sort through? The (1) sum, (2) the mean, (3) the max, (4) another value of all ET1 values across a ISO3 obvservation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is the result you are looking for your question 1. Let me know through a comment if I am mistaken. But I inferred that you want to sort the x axis along the number of cases each ISO3 has. I am making the big assumption here, which might be wrong, that you want the x-axis sorted through the highest value of ET1 among all observation with a common ISO3 value.

```
 library(tidyverse)

 ex1 %>% 
 group_by(ISO3) %>% 
 mutate(ET1_sort = max(ET1)) %>% ## Create a value through which to sort the x axis in the geom_bar()
 ggplot() +
 geom_bar(aes(x = reorder(ISO3, X = ET1_sort), ## Sort here, through reorder
          fill = as.factor(upbound))) + #use as.factor to stack (correct?) //R I think so
 theme(legend.position="none") + # none because there are 1200 values in legend
 xlab("Country") + 
 ylab("ET1") + ## Watch out, this might or might not be representative of ET1. The stack is a sum of observations, which does not necesarily reflect the ET1 values from your df. Again, check if this is true or not.
 coord_flip()
```

Results:

[image: The Figure]

Alternatively, here I sort through the number of observations. This is another big assumption.

```
ex1 %>%
group_by(ISO3) %>%
mutate(ET1_sort = n()) %>% ## Create a value through which to sort the x axis in the geom_bar()
ggplot() +
geom_bar(aes(x = reorder(ISO3, X = ET1_sort), ## Sort here, through reorder
             fill = as.factor(upbound))) + #use as.factor to stack (correct?) //R I think so
theme(legend.position="none") + # none because there are 1200 values in legend
xlab("Country") + 
ylab("ET1") + ## Watch out, this might or might not be representative of ET1. The stack is a sum of observations, which does not necesarily reflect the ET1 values from your df. Again, check if this is true or not.
coord_flip()
```

Results2:

[image: Results2]

Comment: this is a very useful answer. With that help, I am close to the final bar chart. I basically want to the x-axis sorted through the highest value of ET1 and stacked by upbound. Having the number of observations helps a lot because I can use it in the legend and have a nicer visualization. Here is what I have done based on your suggestion

Comment: `ex1 %>%
  group_by(ISO3) %>%
  mutate(ET1_sort = n()) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=reorder(ISO3, X = ET1_sort), y=ET1, fill = as.factor(ET1_sort))) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") +
  xlab("Country (ISO3)") +
  ylab("Global HC potential [u]") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(legend.justification=c(1,0), legend.position = c(1, 0),
        text=element_text(size=16))+
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow=10, title="Number of EDB per country"))`